# Spring REST Controller transactions

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data

I have a Spring RestController MyRestController with RequestMapping myMethod and autowired Spring Data Repository myRepository in it. Inside myMethod I call myRepository: myRepository.save(myEntity) and myRepository.findByMyProperty(...). When does transactions are started? (one before myMethod invocation or several before each myRepository method invocation)?

I'm very confused by this question. Can anybody make it clear for me, please.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the `spring-data` documentation:](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions)

> CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default.

So your the `save()` method is transactional as long as you're using a subclass of `CrudRepository`.

Your query methods are not transactional by default, the documentation says:

> To allow your query methods to be transactional simply use `@Transactional` at the repository interface you define.

So you should annotate your repository:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<My, Long> {
  List<User> findByMyProperty(String myProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Transaction starts before each myRepository method invocation by default, For full control on the Transaction, use @Transactional on each service method that calls the repository method.